# flicker initial badge color when update in badge data

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i am building a game i have shown some history badges ( last 4 game results show up as badges at top ) with red and green color if the value is greater then multiplier ( the multiplier is that how much you need to multiply your amount ) then the color set to be green else color should be red so whenever new data update for few milliseconds  the initial badge color is red its flicker and the color is changing to green that is wrong behaviour

```
const Badge = ({
multiplierList,
setIdx,
setMultiplierList,
setShow,
loadedData
}) => {

const {
    isWinningSound,
    setColorSetter,
    colorSetter
} = useGameContext()


const getButtonColor = (value) => {
    const entry = loadedData?.find(data => data?.final_multiplier === value);
    if (entry) {
        if (multiplierList.length > 4) {
            const tempList = [...multiplierList] tempList.shift() setMultiplierList(tempList)
        }
        return entry?.status === "over" ? "red" : "green"
    }
};

return ( <
    div className = 'history' >
    <
    div className = 'd-flex badge' > {
        multiplierList.map((value, index) => ( <
            div className = 'mx-2'
            key = {
                index
            } > {
                value && < button onClick = {
                    handleShow
                }
                value = {
                    value
                }
                className = "badge rounded-4 text-black "
                style = {
                    {
                        backgroundColor: getButtonColor(value),
                        fontSize: "1rem"
                    }
                } > {
                    value
                }
                x <
                /button>
            } <
            /div>
        ))
    } <
    /div> <
    /div>
);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Does the loadedData come from an API call? If that's the case the component renders before the data is loaded and right after it arrives it rerenders and shows the color based on the data. You can render the content of the component only if you have data available:

```
const Badge = ({
multiplierList,
setIdx,
setMultiplierList,
setShow,
loadedData,
dataLoaded // boolean value to indicate if the data has arrived because you can't know just from the passed array. If it is empty it might be because there are just no history records and not because the API hasn't returned a response yet:
}) => {
   // all your other code...

   // if the API hasn't returned a response yet do not show the content of your component
   if (!dataLoaded) {
      return null;
   }

   // at this point you know that the data has arrived from the API and you can show your content. If the loadedData is empty it is because there are no history records to show.
   return <div>your actual content</div>
}
```

That way you won't render the component until the data has arrived.

Comment: Yes, loadedData is coming from an API call and I have tried what you suggest but it doesn't work. @snaksa

Comment: @LokendraSinghRathore If the loadedData is an array and not an object you might need to check it's length. But that will lead to a bug when there is no data in the array just because there is no history for the player. You need to pass a boolean value to check if the data has arrived and show your content base on that. I edited my answer.

Comment: thank you so much i will appreciate you @snaksa